# Styling Tabs With Right Angle Bracket

Tags: html, css, tabs

I have a multistep form with next button,which will take to next tab.
I want to customise the tab design shown as below,

[image]

I used markers for this, but it is not displaying properly as expected

[image]

Is there anyother way to fix this?

Here is my HTML and CSS Code

```css
#progressbar {
height: 50px;
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
border: 4px solid black;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: space-between;
}

#progressbar div {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: white;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    color: crimson;
}

    #progressbar div:not(:first-child) {
        margin-left: 0px;
    }

    #progressbar div.active {
        background-color: lightcoral;
    }

    #progressbar div:not(:last-child)::before,
    #progressbar div:not(:last-child)::after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
    }

#progressbar .acitive:not(:last-child)::before {
    background-color: lightcoral;
}

#progressbar div.active:not(:last-child)::before {
    background-color: lightcoral;
}

#progressbar div:not(:last-child)::before {
    right: -10px;
    top: 0px;
    height: 60px;
    width: 37px;
    border: 4px solid black;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    z-index: 2;
}

#progressbar div:not(:last-child)::after {
    top: 0px;
    right: 0;
    height: 45px;
    width: 43px;
    background-color: inherit;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div id="progressbar">
                <div class="active" id="Details"><strong>Details&BioData</strong></div>
                <div id="Educational"><strong>Educational Qualification</strong></div>
                <div id="Attachement"><strong>Attachement Of Forms</strong></div>
                <div id="Training Details"><strong>Training Details</strong></div>
                <div id="Confirmation"><strong>Confirmation</strong></div>
            </div>
```

Instead of using markers ,can i use image for separating each tab?Any help would be appreciated.

After setting z-index value to -1

[image]

This is how it looks after setting z-index to 2

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can achieve that easily by using the `::after` and `::before` pseudo element.

I used `div` elements instead of `li` so we can have more control when designing.

Here's an example:

```css
#progressbar {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 4px solid black;

  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#progressbar div {
  padding-left: 4px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  color: crimson;   
}


#progressbar div:not(:first-child) {
  margin-left: 24px;
}

#progressbar div.active {
  background-color: lightcoral;
}

#progressbar div:not(:last-child)::before,
#progressbar div:not(:last-child)::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
} 

#progressbar .acitive:not(:last-child)::before {
  background-color: lightcoral;
}

#progressbar div.active:not(:last-child)::before {
 background-color: lightcoral;
}

#progressbar div:not(:last-child)::before {
  right: -13.5px;
  top: -1px;
  height: inherit;
  width:  30px;
  border: 4px solid black;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  z-index: -1;
}

#progressbar div:not(:last-child)::after {
  top: 0px;
  right: 0;
  height: inherit;
  width: 80%;
  background-color: inherit;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div id="progressbar">
  <div class="active" id="Details"><strong>Details&BioData</strong></div>
  <div id="Educational"><strong>Educational Qualification</strong></div>
  <div id="Attachement"><strong>Attachement Of Forms</strong></div>
  <div id="Training Details"><strong>Training Details</strong></div>
  <div id="Confirmation"><strong>Confirmation</strong></div>
</div>
```

Happy Coding!

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation. I need one help also,say for example the div text is "Educational Qualification" instead of step3.then the letters are not fully shown.The ::after element 'width' is hiding the text.Is there anyway to show this letters?Thanks in Advance

Comment: I've edited the code snippet. You just have to set the `z-index`of both `::before` `::after` pseudo element to `-1`. :)

Comment: @Teena also don't forget to upvote the answer ;)

Comment: Hi, I have made the changes then what happens is the arrow mark is disappearing,Since my text is long i changed the div height to 50px and some related changes. But still i got the problem. I have edited my code.

Comment: Hi @Teena, I just saw your updated code, You set the `z-index: 2` for your `::before` and `::after` pseudo element. That is what we want to avoid, we want that 2 pseudo element to bring it back to the text so it will not overlap. To bring it back to the text, please set `z-index: -1` for both pseudo element. You can also look at my code as your reference.

Comment: Hi @Techuila, Thanks for the response. I have updated my question.could you please have a look.I have captured the display of both ,when im using z-index as -1 the arrow is disppearing,thats why i used z-index as 2 .But when i use 2 text wont display.Thanks for the understanding.

Comment: Hi @Teena, sorry for the late response, I've now updated the code on my answer, is it now good?

Comment: Hi @Techuila,thanks for the reply and sorry for the late response. i coudnt fix it by changing z-index to -1. Without changing the z-index value to -1 , i made some adjustments in ::after and ::before elements. Took some time to fix it :). Thanks for the help and detailed explanation.